# For Loop that calculates sum of squred numbers in array

Tags: javascript

I am working on a challenge and in need of some help:
Write a for loop that calculates sum of squares of items in an array of numbers. Example: For array [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] it calculates the sum of squares as 30 (i.e. 1 + 4 + 9 + 16). I have a fiddle set up if anyone wants to have a closer look. Thanks for your help!

https://jsfiddle.net/jamie_shearman/2drt56e3/23/

```
var aFewNumbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 7 ];

var squareOfAFewNumbers = 0;

for( var i = 0; i <= aFewNumbers; i++ ) {
    squareOfAFewNumbers = squareOfAFewNumbers * aFewNumbers[i] ;
  }

console.log( squareOfAFewNumbers );
```

Comment: `[1,2,3,4].reduce((a, v) => (a += v*v, a), 0)`

Comment: Where do you actually sum things?

Comment: @Keith If you're going for conciseness, you don't need more than one statement in the return value of the callback. You don't have to modify a, the next iteration will just use whatever value you return. So it can be just `[1,2,3,4].reduce((a, v) => a + v * v, 0)`

Comment: When you loop over an array, the condition in the `for` loop should be `< arrayname.length`.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk  Force of habit, I'm so used to doing more with the accumulator..  But yes, that can be skipped in this example.  In fact you can even skip the `,0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your math is wrong. As an obvious issue, the variable starts at 0 and then is multiplied by each array element; 0 times anything is 0, so it will always remain 0 no matter what the values are. Not to mention your loop isn't looking at the length of the array as a stopping condition, which it should be, since you want to iterate from the beginning to the end of the array.

You need to iterate through to the array's length, square each array element, and *add* that square to the variable:

```
for( var i = 0; i < aFewNumbers.length; i++ ) {
    squareOfAFewNumbers += aFewNumbers[i] * aFewNumbers[i];
}
```

If you can use ES6, you can even use higher-order array functions to simplify this more:

```
var squareOfAFewNumbers = aFewNumbers.reduce((result, entry) => result + entry * entry, 0);
```

Comment: `<=` should be `<`.

Comment: Good catch. That's the problem with copypasta editing :D  Thanks.

Comment: IceMetalPunk da Man! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript `pow()` Method to create the square and sum it to the `sumSquareOfAFewNumbers`.

```js
var aFewNumbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 7 ];

var sumSquareOfAFewNumbers = 0;

aFewNumbers.forEach(function(element) {
   sumSquareOfAFewNumbers += Math.pow(element, 2);
});
  
console.log(sumSquareOfAFewNumbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches you can take for reaching the desired result, but as you've mentioned that you must write a `for` loop; therefore, I sorted the answers by having that in mind.

**Using the for loop**

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 7],
    sum = 0;

for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum += Math.pow(numbers[i], 2)
}

// Sum is now 63
```

**Using forEach method of the array object**

```
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 7],
    sum = 0;

numbers.forEach(number => sum += Math.pow(number, 2))

// Sum is now 63
```

**Oneliner**

```
let sum = [1, 2, 3, 7].reduce((a, c) => a + Math.pow(c, 2))
```

The reduce method uses an `accumulator` to store temporary results, the accumulator is passed to the callback as the first argument and the second argument is the element's value, you can read more about the `reduce` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).